# Authenticate against Exchange web service using existing credentials

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

We have a web application that use forms authentication against Active Directory. In the same domain we also have an Exchange server 2010, soon to be 2013.

My question is, I would like to use the Exchange server to send outgoing emails from the user account using Exchange Web Services(EWS). Is it possible to reuse the user authentication that is already done on the form to connecto the the EWS?

We are using c#

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but it's covered here: [Accessing internal Exchange web services from an external application through ISA server using forms-based authentication](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/accessing-internal-exchange-web-services-from-an-external-application-through-isa-server-using-forms-based-authentication/).

Comment: Yeah.. Thank you for your reply. ISA server are discontinued from Microsoft so I will not make my bet there.